# How to print last non-blank line using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I would like get last non-blank line from a file using sed. I was able to achieve expected result using two pipelined sed:

```
$ echo -e "\n\none\n\ntwo\n\n\nthree\n\n" | sed '/^$/d' | sed -n '$p'
three
```

However, I wonder if is it possible to get that using just one sed command. Maybe by copying each non-blank line to the buffer one after another, overwriting previous content and printing the buffer at the end? I am not sure if it can be done in sed, it is just my guess.

Please don't propose me to use awk, tail, etc - I am interested just in sed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe :

```
sed -e '/^$/d' -e '$ !d'
```

?

Other way with hold buffer:

```
sed -e '/^$/ !h
        $ {x;p;}'
```

Comment: Benoit, the second way with hold buffer is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You left out the -n the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "\n\none\n\ntwo\n\n\nthree\n\n" |
sed '/^$/!h;$!d;g'
three
```